# How to send an email notification when an external users download a file shared

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, workflow, office-365

I have a situation where external users are given access to SharePoint. The Client wants to setup a functionality in such a way as let's say if an external user downloads a file shared with them then it should send an email notification to a person let's say an admin.

I checked in flow, there is no such way to do this in Flow, can someone please help me out with the approach for this, how to achieve this in SharePoint, maybe a workflow, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any triggers on opening or downloading a document. So flow, or workflow won't work.

The only option I see is to use the Office 365 Security & Compliance center to check the activities in the audit log. I don't know if you can automate anything on the audit log.